# Automount EFS to ECS on EC2 instance termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I want to persist my mongodb data in ecs cluster using EFS. So, I followed the below approach.

1. created a cluster under EC2 instance
2. Attached EFS to the EC2 cluster Instance
3. Created task definitions and services.
4. Ran services on the EFS mounted EC2 Cluster

Now, everything is going smooth when the containers are getting updated or terminated. But, when the entire ec2 instance is terminated. AWS cloud formation is creating EC2 instance without mounting EFS as expected. Can someone help me how to get EFS attached automatically when the EC2 instance gets terminated and recreated by CloudFormation. I even tried custom ecs images. But, the instances are not getting created as there is no cloud formation template getting created.

Comment: This idea is kind of interesting. For your question, I would suggest you put the mounting script in the user-data. But I don't see any benefit to persist your mongodb data on EFS since it's super slow compared to EBS.

Comment: Hi @kakashi, Can you please elaborate a bit more on how to pass user data when creating ECS cluster from dashboard. I know how to pass it for custom agent while creating ec2 instance. But not sure how to do that for ECS cluster directly.

Comment: you can try to follow the instruction according to the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html#instance-launch-user-data-step

Comment: Thanks for the info Kakashi. The above link will create a default cluster. But, on termination of EC2 instance, it won't spin new ec2-instance and attach that to the cluster. Second point here we should consider is ECS agents can only register to default cluster or existing cluster. But, they can't create a new cluster according to the following link https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/826

Comment: Why don't you bring ECS cluster using ASG and with User data as @kakashi suggested?. Here is example for mounting EFS at EC2 start.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_efs.html.
If you are planning on creating new ECS cluster every time, CF template could do that easily and refer the newly created cluster as part of User Data. Let me know if you want example CF which does this.

Comment: Auto-scaling group will bring up the instance but not the data which was lost with the EBS volume stored in old instance.

Comment: ECS can mount the EFS drive for you when a task is deployed as long as the task definition is setup correctly.  If you can post your task definition and instance role, we can point you in the right direction.